# How to develop vendored libraries?

Tags: go, dependencies

I recently jumped back into an old Go project and migrated it to the *vendor* approach, using `dep`

It completed sucessfully and I now have a bunch of libs in the local projects `vendor/` directory. Great!

However, I now want to work on one of those vendored libs, and see the changes in my main app live. The lib exists in its own project of course, doesn't live its life in this other apps vendor folder - and other local projects should be able to see the live changes too if necessary.

I'm thinking something like `npm link`, to compare across ecosystems.

How is this typically managed in Go?

Comment: make changes to the project, then update the dependency in the vendor folder with one of dep's commands https://golang.github.io/dep/docs/daily-dep.html#updating-dependencies (maybe you'll have to commit and even push? the changes before you do dep ensure -update, try and see).

Comment: Doesn't seem to work - `dep ensure` will replace it with the version on github it seems, not with my local version in GOPATH

Comment: I see you added about commit/push - right, but I want to see the changes live locally before commit/push. There could be temp debug messages, logs, etc.

Comment: I guess I could just delete the folder in `vendor` and make it a symlink, though that's a little scary since `dep` won't know about that

Comment: don't do symlinks man

Comment: Need a solution here though ;)

Comment: If you don't care about what dm you're using ditch `dep` and use `govendor` instead. It allows you to update deps from `$GOPATH`.

Comment: Symlinks wouldn't work anyway, btw.  If you were working on package `foo`, and both your project and `foo` depended on and imported `bar`, then if you symlinked `foo` in, it would still be physically present in your actual GOPATH and would be using the version of `bar` present there (or failing to compile if it weren't present).  If you tried to pass a `bar.Baz` from your package to `foo`, you'd get a type error.  Personally, we use govendor, which lets you update from GOPATH, but you can also simply move everything from the vendor folder to your GOPATH during development.

Comment: Don't just make your changes locally, make them and push them to the repo and let vendoring work normally.

Comment: I basically wouldn't vendor a package that I'm still working on

Comment: simply delete the corresponding folder from the `vendor`, git checkout the corresponding lib into your `gopath`, adjust its git position, do the actual code in both items, finally return to your dependency, bump/publish it, return to the main project, bump its dependencies, bump/publish it. So basically vendoring works well for dependencies that are truly independent, as soon as you have close concerns and/or life cycle, its a pain in the ass and having one master seems better.